# Rust Trunk can't get environment variables with powershell

Tags: rust, trunk-rs

While trying to use tailwindcss, some tutorial I found online uses this hook configuration:

```ini
[[hooks]]
stage = "build"
command = "sh"
command_arguments = ["-c", "tailwind -i ./src/tailwind.css -o $TRUNK_STAGING_DIR/tailwind.css"]
```

I do not have `sh` available on this machine so I tried installing the tailwind cli and using it as the `command`:

```ini
[[hooks]]
stage = "build"
command = "tailwindcss"
command_arguments = ["-i", "./src/tailwind.css", "-o", "$TRUNK_STAGING_DIR/tailwind.css"]
```

This does execute, but instead of creating the file in the trunk staging directory, it created a new folder literally called `$TRUNK_STAGING_DIR` in my working directory.

So, since I am running this from a Powershell terminal, I tried `$($env:TRUNK_STAGING_DIR)` to access the environment variable. But of course I am getting an error.

```ini
[[hooks]]
stage = "build"
command = "tailwindcss"
command_arguments = ["-i", "./src/tailwind.css", "-o", "$($env:TRUNK_STAGING_DIR)/tailwind.css"]
```

```
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir 'C:\project_path\$($Env:TRUNK_STAGING_DIR)'] {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'mkdir',
  path: 'C:\\project_path\\$($Env:TRUNK_STAGING_DIR)'
}
```

Is this a bug? Is there something else I should know to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$TRUNK_STAGING_DIR` syntax for environment variables is specific to the `sh` shell and its cousins. When you execute `tailwindcss` directly, the only things that could expand the environment variable are Trunk or Tailwind, since this string never touches your current shell. It would be unusual for Tailwind to do it, and it's apparent that Trunk doesn't do it. If you want to use `pwsh`'s expansion, you can use it in place of `sh`:

```ini
[[hooks]]
stage = "build"
command = "pwsh"
command_arguments = ["-Command", "tailwindcss -i ./src/tailwind.css -o $env:TRUNK_STAGING_DIR/tailwind.css"]
```

`pwsh` is for [PowerShell Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/differences-from-windows-powershell?view=powershell-7.4). If you're using Windows PowerShell instead, change the name to `powershell`. Or if you want to use `cmd`, the environment variable syntax is a little different:

```ini
[[hooks]]
stage = "build"
command = "cmd"
command_arguments = ["/C", "tailwindcss -i ./src/tailwind.css -o %TRUNK_STAGING_DIR%/tailwind.css"]
```

Comment: this makes a lot of sense, somehow my setup curently only worked with cmd. And I feel dumb for not trying it haha, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Just to give some kind of answer, it does work by using the staging directory directly:

```ini
[[hooks]]
stage = "build"
command = "tailwindcss"
command_arguments = ["-i", "./src/tailwind.css", "-o", "./dist/.stage/tailwind.css"]
```

But I don't think that avoiding the environment variables really is a good answer.